# Entity failed to be modified with Entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I used Entity Framework in my Web Api application like this :

```
 [HttpPut]
    public System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult UpdateAccount(CollaborateurModel item)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ApplicationUser user = UserManager.FindByIdAsync(item.id_user_fk).Result;
            user.Roles.Clear();
            UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(item.id_user_fk, item.Role);
            ajt_collaborator entity = Mapper.Map<CollaborateurModel, ajt_collaborator>(item);
            repo.UpdateCollaborateur(entity);
            return new System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult { Data = true };
        }
        else
        {
            return new System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult { Data = false };
        }
    }
```

**In BLL**

```
 public void UpdateCollaborateur( ajt_collaborator collaborateur)
        {
            if (cruder == null) cruder = new Crud<ajt_collaborator>();
            cruder.Update(collaborateur);
        }
```

**In DAL**

```
public bool Update(params T[] items)
        {
            if (context == null) context = GetContext();
            try
            {
                foreach (T item in items)
                {
                    context.Entry(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

An exception is thrown in the `Update` method

> Failed attaching a type of entity "sport.DAL.Entities.ajt_collaborator " because another entity of the same type already has this primary key value . This can occur when you use the "Attach " method or set the " Unchanged " value or "Modified" to the state of an entity, whether entities graphic feature key values ​​in conflict. Some entities may be new and may have not received any key values ​​generated by the database . In this case , use the "Add" method or the " Added " entity to draw the graph and assign the value " Unchanged " or " Modified" to the state entities other than the new entities .

I need to know

1. What is the reason of this exception?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: Instead of `Mapper.Map<CollaborateurModel, ajt_collaborator>(item);` can you do a `Find` on the entities and then use that object for update?

Comment: @ramiramilu do you mean find the entity and then fill it by the CollaborateurModel's properties  instead of convert it using Automapper? How can this change the result?

Comment: I think `Mapper.Map` giving you an new object, and then you are setting `Modified` to that new object. But there is already a object exists with same `id`. Thats why you are getting that error. So do a `find`, use that object for `Mapper.Map` to map the `CollaborateurModel` properties to object, then use it for update.

Comment: Have you tried the way I mentioned, there can be potentially other object with different tracking state.

Comment: @ramiramilu Can you please elaborate your idea as an answer

Comment: `ajt_collaborator entity` should be populated by `Find` or `where`, then map all the properties from `item` to `entity`. Then use that entity for update

Comment: Glad I am able to solve your problem. Posted the same as solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not populate `ajt_collaborator entity` as shown below -

```
ajt_collaborator entity = Mapper.Map<CollaborateurModel, ajt_collaborator>(item);
```

Instead Populate `ajt_collaborator entity` using `Find` (or `Where` etc., so that there will not be a new object, but we can get the existing object which was already present in entities), then map all the properties from `item` to `entity` using `Automapper`. Finally use the mapped entity for update purpose.

Answer (score 1):

1. EF thinks that the context and the database are out of sync because you are marking an item as modified but it doesnt have a value set for its primary key.
2. The typical pattern for handling this is to check the PK field and set the entity state accordingly:

`context.Entry(item).State = (item.PK == default(int)) ? System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added : System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;`

(where default(int) is the datatype of your PK)

In your case, the problem can be solved most likely by making sure the PK / key field is even being sent to that method so it is not missing when being automapped or by refetching the item from the DB before calling your Update method.

Answer (score 1):

It also might be that your `item` is received without primary key, or primary key might be lost after mapping.

Comment: Does `CollaborateurModel`  id property has same name as `ajt_collaborator` id ? Maybe you have incorrect auto mapper configuration.

Comment: it is the same name, I check the primary key is passed to BLL method then it is passed to the DAL method

Comment: Well looking at [MSDN blog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx) you did everything correctly, you can try wrapping it with using or before setting `state` attach `context.Attach(item);`

Comment: `context.Attach(item)` gives me an error in EF6. I have to mention the entity class before for example `context.Blogs.Attach(existingBlog);` . How can I do this in my example?